# Google analytics customer data?

Tags: google-analytics

My portal is SaaS based and incidentally all the clients are on the same url.
Lets say www.xyz.com, I differentiate between clients using the session I set while logging.

I want to put in google analytics now, the only problem is that i won't be able to analyze client specific data.

Is there a way to pass client data in google analytics which can be tracked along with the usual traffic.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Use [setCustomVar](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html)
2. The actual URL and the URL you track needn't be the same. Instead of http://www.xyz.com/ you could as well track http://www.xyz.com/customerA/ or http://www.xyz.com/?customer=A

Comment: Does Google Analytics track query parameters (i.e. in your example the customer=A)?

Comment: yes. however, you can always customize what is tracked using the optional parameter to trackPageview, see http://j.mp/9Mu8tB

Comment: just a followup question on privacy, will changing the page tag be sufficient such that users of Google Analytics Account B will not be able to see data and stats from Account A? Both accounts are targeting the same website