# Google Analytics Embeded API without login Google Account

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics-api

i am working on asp.net c# and my question is
suppose my website is(www.abc.com) and my admin panel is(adminabc.com)
and now i have create google analytics account with www.abc.com and get records successfully from my admin panel
but right now if i login from my admin panel that time charts is not display.

In my admin panel one google analytics button are display and if i click on button and enter username and password of my google account then after i will see the chart on my admin panel

so my question is it is possible to see chart without login with google analytics or can i pass google account credential on script that i put from my .aspx page.

pleae help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't included any code so its hard for me to know exactly how you have created this admin panel on your website.  Assuming that you are using the Google Analytics api Create a service account will allow you to access the Google Analytics API without authenticating.

Comment: Hi i have follow this link : https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/                                please check this link.................

Comment: also please suggest me how to get records using google analytics service account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics Embed API: How to retireve access token?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070463/google-analytics-embed-api-how-to-retireve-access-token)

Comment: i didn't understand can you please give me the any url then explain me how to get google analytics chart and records from my asp.net c# admn panel.................please help me

Comment: Alternatively you should look into setting up server-side auth as in this example: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

Comment: At the end of the day you need to use the Core Reporting API/OAuth.  Are you entering the username/password client side?  if so, then you are not using oAuth.  If you are using oAuth then you would be re-directed to Google to authenticate/authorize.  Then you webapp must store the refresh token.  Every hour you would need to query Google to get a new access token.  If you don't want to deal with the Core Reporting API and oAuth, check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com - we specialize in displaying GA based reports outside of GA.