# Google analytics "invalid credentials"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i have written code which sent request for `access_token` and get successfully
code is below (node.js)

```
authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) 
{res.json(tokens);}
```

After getting this token successfully when i pass this token to here, i got error "invalid credentials"

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '{{token}}'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are a full example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<section id="timeline"></section>

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  var IDS = 'ENTER YOUR IDS VAUE HERE'; // e.g. 'ga:1174'
  var ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ENTER VALID ACCESS TOKEN'; // obtained from your service account

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    serverAuth: {
      access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
  });

  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'ids': IDS,
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
  }).execute();

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this was extracted from google documentation, for full reference click [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started?hl=en-419)
and check [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests) link too and if all fails check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896826/using-google-analytics-to-show-subset-of-data-for-customers-of-web-application-u) stackoverflow post